# What is the best practice to do with temporary (unused) list?

Tags: python

I've a code snippet below which gets the dataclass variables (keys) with "_dg" prefix, then gets the attribute of each key according to declaration order and appends them into a list. At the end this will be merged into a single element and returned as a string.

```
def create_decrypted_EFSOD(self) -> str:

    _ = []
    try:
        for attr in list(self.__dict__.keys()):
            if attr.startswith("_dg"):
                _.append(self.__getattribute__(attr))

        return "".join(_)

    finally:
        del _
```

Where my dataclass is declared as:

```
@dataclass
class PassiveAuthenticator:
    """
    Passive Authentication of eMRTD Documents for Inspection Systems (IFD's). Protects against IC forging.

    Refers to "Doc. 9303, Machine Readable Travel Documents, Part 11 - Security Mechanisms for MRTDS" by ICAO, 2021,
    Section 6.1 and Appendix G for more details about security protocols.

    """
    _dg1: str
    _dg2: str
    _dg3: str
    .
    .
```

I know the `_` variable always refers to last returned value, that is why I used it to avoid creating unnecessary variable, but creating a temporary variable still bothers me. **What is the best practice for this situation?**

Also, does deleting `_` variable mean anything since it'll be redeclared again? Since I'm a C++ dev it's a habit to deallocate.

Comment: You should **not** name the variable `_`, that name is mostly used for variable that are unused but your variable *is* very much used. Name it `attributes` or `attributes_with_prefix` or something like that. And no, you should not be deleting `_` explicitly.

Comment: You don't need to manually delete anything. Python has built-in GC that aims to eliminate manual handling.

Comment: No, a `_` variable doesn't refer to last returned value. That might be the case in some IDEs or REPLs, but it's not a feature of Python.

Comment: There is no need to create list of keys (`list(self.__dict__.keys())`) or initialize a temp list in advance. You can use list comprehension/generator expression and do just `return "".join(attr for attr in self.__dict__ if attr.startswith("_dg"))`
`

Comment: @buran thanks, that was my initial  code, but I've changed it during code review to increase readability.   I'm able to access the tags (attr names) with the snippet you suggested. But I couldn't get the values ( what _dg1 is assigned) within the same line without  creating temporary  list.

Comment: `return "".join(value for attr, value in self.__dict__.items() if attr.startswith("_dg"))`

Comment: @luk2302 that works like a charm, I can accept it if you post this as an answer . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EgeYıldırım, my bad - I overlooked that you access the values as well. luk2302 answer is what I would suggest too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat what was already said in the comments:

- no, `_` does not refer to the last returned variable
- no, `_` is not a good name for the variable, it should be used on variables that are unused but your variable *is* used
- no, python has automatic GC and you do not need to explicitly `del _`.

Therefore your code should simply be

```
def create_decrypted_EFSOD(self) -> str:
    matching_attributes = []
    for attr in list(self.__dict__.keys()):
        if attr.startswith("_dg"):
            matching_attributes.append(self.__getattribute__(attr))

    return "".join(matching_attributes)
```

or simplified using a generator expression

```
def create_decrypted_EFSOD(self) -> str:
    return "".join(value for attr, value in self.__dict__.items() if attr.startswith("_dg"))
```